# Android 4 does not accept negative inset

Tags: android, imageview, android-4.4-kitkat, layer-list

I have an ImageView with a layer-list as source. The layer-list consists of an image and a frame. The frame has a negative inset of -4dp. This works great on Android 5 and above, but not on any Android 4 versions (tested on actual devices with 4.3 and 4.4.2).

On Android 5 and above devices, the frame is outside the actual image (the frame width is 4dp) but on Android 4 devices, the frame is inside the image.

layer list xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/image_id">
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/checker_bmp"
            android:antialias="true"/>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/shadow">
        <inset
            android:antialias="true"
            android:inset="-4dp">
            <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/green_shadow"/>
        </inset>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[InsetDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/InsetDrawable.html) exists since API version 1.

I can not use the standard android:src and android:background for image and frame because I have to rotate the image and the background isn't capable of rotating with the ImageView.

Here is the result: The red and black checkerboard is the actual image. The transparent green frame shows the result of the xml on different Android versions. the negative inset should put the green frame around the checkerboard, like it does on Android 5+. On Android 4 it is inside the image, like it is ignored. How to achieve the correct result on Android 4?

[image: result]

EDIT: I found out that `android:inset` is only available from API level 21 (Android 5). There must be a way to get the same result on API levels below 21... Important is that the image must be able to scale and rotate and that the frame is a nine patch drawable.

EDIT2: Giving the imageview a positive inset instead gives the same result. This is the code I used:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/image_id">
        <inset
            android:antialias="true"
            android:inset="4dp">
            <bitmap
                android:src="@drawable/checker_bmp"
                android:antialias="true"/>
        </inset>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/shadow" >
        <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/green_shadow"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Setting 4dp padding on the image makes the whole image offset by 4dp:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/canvas_image_layer_id" android:top="4dp" android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp">

            <bitmap
                android:src="@drawable/canvas_shadow"
                android:antialias="true"/>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/background_shadow" >
        <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/canvas_shadow"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a negative inset, put the frame first as a solid color, then put the image as a positive inset into that.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The border isn't actually a solid color, but a gradient with an offset center as a nine patch drawable. I only use the green border for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Same difference.  You need to put the inset on the image.  Negative insets/margins/etc were never supposed to work, they did as a bug that developers took advantage of, and then Google decided not to fix.  Google has gone back and forth on whether they're supported or not, and the current world is inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Please see my EDIT2 for results.